# Tag merge request: [tika] into [apache-tika]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The shiny new profile page just prompted me to go for the [apache-tika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tika) badge, which was a surprise as I thought I already had it, but that was actually [tika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tika). I've done some checks, and we have a fair number using one or the other, and some with both. All of the questions on both tags refer to Apache Tika, as do the tag wikis

In keeping with many of the other Apache Software Foundation project tags, I'd suggest making [apache-tika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tika) the canonical one, and [tika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tika) a synonym

Answer (score 1):

[tika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tika) -> [apache-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tiki) - merged and syn'd.

Comment: It's tik*a* with an *a* not an *i* !

Comment: @Gagravarr a typo in the answer - not the actual merging - thanks.