# Make [mina] and [apache-mina] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The title is pretty much self-explanatory.

Here are both of the tags' excerpts:

[image: mina]

[image: apache-mina]

On a side note: I've been noticing this happens a lot with Apache products. Is there a more generic solution for this problem?

Examples:

- [There is no [spark] but [apache-spark]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271857/there-is-no-spark-but-apache-spark)
- [Make [jena] and [apache-jena] synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319661/make-jena-and-apache-jena-synonyms)
- [Please make the tag [zookeeper] a synonym of [apache-zookeeper]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361655/please-make-the-tag-zookeeper-a-synonym-of-apache-zookeeper)
- [Merge tags [flink] and [apache-flink]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307130/merge-tags-flink-and-apache-flink?s=12|48.3457)
- [Tag merge request: [tika] into [apache-tika]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300902/tag-merge-request-tika-into-apache-tika?s=13|47.1880)
- [Synonymize [tomee] and [apache-tomee]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311802/synonymize-tomee-and-apache-tomee)

Comment: The synonym was suggested on Nov 1 '10 at 22:27. Approved now